# Adding random numbers to a variable

Tags: python, random

I'm looking for an output like this

```
Computer Choice: 5
Total: 5
Continue? Yes or No
Computer Choice:2
Total: 7
```

It adds up the random numbers every time it's created. This is the part I'm trying to get to work:

```
 if player_bet <= Player.total_money_amount:

    import random
    computer_choice = random.randint(1, 5) # Creates random number
    computer_total =+ computer_choice # Does not work. Also used += same result
    print('Computer choice: ', computer_choice)
                print('Total: ', computer_total)

      player_yes_or_no = input('Continue? Yes or No')
      if player_yes_or_no == 'Yes':
      pass
```

Current output

```
Computer Choice: 5
Total: 5
Continue? Yes or No
Computer Choice: 2
Total: 2
```

As you can see it does not add up the random int that where created. 
If I do +=  it gives an error

Edit: I get the same output when I do

```
 computer_total = 0
 computer_total += computer_choice
```

Comment: First of all, you need += not =+

Comment: You also need to fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `=+` to `+=`. The way you currently have it you are reassigning the variable `computer_total` to the value of `computer_choice` rather than adding them. Also, make sure to initialize `computer_total` before you start your loop.

Comment: Does not work.  I created a new variable computer_total = 0 Then I used the += and it's the same output

Comment: @PrQ did you try using +=? =+ will not work as you want it to.

Comment: Yep I used both += and =+ it gives the same output

Comment: @PrQ it seems like you are resetting computer_total to 0 every time, so that will not keep a running total. I would have to see more of your program to figure out what you need.

Comment: Could the problem be because it's in a while loop?

Comment: @PrQ you probably need to set the variable to 0 *before* your while loop starts then, not in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
#Added intilization.
import random
computer_choice = 0
computer_total = 0
for i in range(5): #Just added to make it running. You can add you checkings here

    computer_choice = random.randint(1, 5) 
    computer_total += computer_choice 
    print('Computer choice: ', computer_choice)
    print('Total: ', computer_total)
    #Changed input to raw_input
    player_yes_or_no = str(raw_input("Computer Choice - Yes or No ? "))
    if player_yes_or_no == 'Yes':
        next
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python demo.Py
('Computer choice: ', 2)
('Total: ', 2)
Computer Choice - Yes or No ? Yes
('Computer choice: ', 5)
('Total: ', 7)
Computer Choice - Yes or No ? Yes
('Computer choice: ', 2)
('Total: ', 9)
Computer Choice - Yes or No ? Yes
('Computer choice: ', 2)
('Total: ', 11)
Computer Choice - Yes or No ? Yes
('Computer choice: ', 2)
('Total: ', 13)
```

Comment: You are importing random every time the for loop is executed. Just import it once at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `computer_total` outside of the loop first for it to work:

```
import random

computer_total= 0

while True:
    computer_choice = random.randint(1, 5) # Creates random number
    computer_total += computer_choice 
    print('Computer choice: ', computer_choice)
    print('Total: ', computer_total)

    player_yes_or_no = input('Continue? Yes or No\n')
    if player_yes_or_no == 'Yes':
        pass
```

I put the code inside an infinite loop for testing.
Note that I import random outside of the loop, so that it is not re-imported unnecessarily every time the loop runs. I also added a newline to the end of the `input()` call.